# Working with DOM elements in react testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-forwardref

I have what I think is a general question about working with DOM elements in React Testing library.

Essentially, I have a couple of nested components, one of which creates a React ref that is forwarded down to some child components (code below).

When it does this, it then renders the child components and checks the nested Ref to call `.getBoundingClientRect()` a magical native Javascript function that gives me the x and y positioning, the width & height, and top, bottom, left & right bounds. I really need this information because I want to do some other things with it, without directly modifying the DOM (I am making all my DOM modifications using setState and letting React re-render the DOM)

In development (Chrome), when I do `console.log(this.thing_one_ref.current.getBoundingClientRect())` I get this result:
[image]

(you'll note that thing_one_ref here is correctly populated once my app renders-- not before-- and looks like:)

[image]

I have a simple spec for this code, which happens to pass, but even though it passes, the console logged output *when in the test environment* looks like this:

[image]

Notice that all of the values are 0 instead of what I am expecting, which is the element to be rendered as-if it were on a real DOM

// src/App.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, wait } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
test('renders learn react link', async () => {
  const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(<App />);
  const linkElement = getByTestId("app")
  await wait(() => expect(getByText(/A Test of refs/i, linkElement)).toBeInTheDocument());
});
```

// src/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import styled from 'styled-components'

import ThingOne from './thing_one'
import Container from './container'

const StyledApp = styled.div`
   position: relative;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
`

function App() {
  return (
    <StyledApp data-testid="app" className="App" style={{position: 'relative'}}>
      <Container />
    </StyledApp>
  );
}

export default App;
```

// src/container.js

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import ThingOne from "./thing_one";
const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  display: block;
`

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.thing_one_ref = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      message: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({message: "A test of refs"})

      // here's the console.log
      console.log(this.thing_one_ref.current.getBoundingClientRect())
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    const {message} = this.state
    return (
      <StyledContainer>
        {message}
        <ThingOne ref={this.thing_one_ref}/>
      </StyledContainer>
    )
  }
}

export default Container
```

// src/thing_one.js

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledThingOne = styled.div`
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 20px;
`
const ThingOne = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <StyledThingOne ref={ref}></StyledThingOne>
));

export default ThingOne
```

How do I get the test environment to behave as-if it is mounted in a real DOM, complete with a cartesian plane that I can use for trigonometry and animation?  I have some working code that depends on the result of `getBoundingClientRect()` looking something like this result (as said above, work in browser)

```
DOMRect {x: 225.1875, y: 38, width: 102, height: 102, top: 38, …}
```

complete source code can be referenced here:

https://github.com/jasonfb/jest-playground-3

Comment: Related: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1590

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this goes beyond your current requirements, but you may consider running your test suites on an actual browser (real DOM environment), rather than [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom), which is used by Jest to simulate a browser-like environment on Node.JS.

You may consider using test frameworks like [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/) and [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) to carry out tests on supported browsers such as Chrome. This will allow you to carry out Integration testing (what you are trying to achieve), and in the future, End to End testing on the browser. This will eliminate the need to mock/stub/simulate DOM elements on Node.JS.

Comment: yes that sounds like a good direction for me. I am (relatively) new to the React eco system but have been doing testing in other languages for many years. Is there a way to keep writing JS code (like Jest) and use a headless or real browser? (Like, previously I've used phantomjs, Selenium with poltergeist, Webkit, etc, scripted with Ruby)... I guess what I'm looking for is a way to use JEST to script a real browser or at least a headless browser that simulates the DOM more accurately?

Comment: I guess what i really want to know is, which of these are the best options for a React app ?

Comment: this looks interesting but it looks a little complicated to set up: https://medium.com/@mathieux51/jest-selenium-webdriver-e25604969c6 … could be promising

Comment: looks like with jest selenium driver you basically just have access to the driver object itself, and then all of your specs need to be written in the selenium format (getElementById, getElementByXPath, etc…) which I don't *prefer* but it could be an option maybe

Comment: @JasonFB yes, there are a indeed a bunch of options when it comes to this, but if you are looking for simplicity when it comes to integration, why not give Cypress a shot? Regardless of what you choose, both Selenium and Cypress will allow you to run the tests headless or with the browser itself.

Comment: thank you very much. I am reading through this now : https://blog.bitsrc.io/testing-react-apps-with-cypress-658bc482678 .... quick question: Is there a way to show a code coverage report with Cypress? Ideally, what I'd like is to be able to get all the code coverage in one report, so I could write some (basic) tests with Jest and use Cypress for things that needed more advanced testing, but still see a singular coverage report that shows which lines are covered and which ones are not. Is that possible? I assume if Cypress has its own coverage report then it will show me the report for itself.

Comment: @JasonFB Yes, like many test frameworks, Cypress supports code coverage. You may read it more about it here! https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage.html#Introduction

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but perhaps this can help, In your tests you can override the default HTMLElement method for getBoundingClientRect and return mocked results just like this:

```
function domRect(x, y, width, height) {
    return {x, y, width, height, top: y, bottom: y + height, left: x, right: x + width} as unknown as DOMRect
}

// imagine you want to mock DOMRect for a certain element with data-testid="testid"
const mockRect = domRect(0, 0, 150, 50)

const mockBoundingClientRects = () => {
    const getBoundingClientRect = HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect;
    HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = function() {
        const elmt:HTMLElement = this;
        // implement here ways to differentiate elements you want to override getBoundingClientRect for
        // here we're looking for element with data-testid="testid"
        if ((elmt.children?.[0] as HTMLElement)?.dataset?.testid === 'testid') {
            return mockRect
        }
        return getBoundingClientRect.bind(this)()
    }
}
```

You can then call mockBoundingClientRect() inside your test or before step.

You will probably also want to mock window.innerHeight/innerWidth and/or window.scrollX/scrollY, for that simply set them to desired values in your test.

hope this can help.